# Does Northern Kurdish actually have a paucal number?

Tags: indo-european, grammatical-number, plurality, paucal

For the past 10+ years, the Wikipedia article "Grammatical number" has stated:

> Of the Indo-European languages, Kurmanji (also known as Northern Kurdish) is one of the few known languages with paucal number. For instance: car-IN-an (sometimes), cf. gelek car-an (many times) and car (time). Another example is sêv-IN-an (some apples), sêvan (the apples), sêv (apple). It can be applied to basically all nouns.

After a long time searching, I cannot find a single academic source that describes Kurdish as having a paucal. It seems like the example inflection change from sêvan to sêvinan is a change from oblique definite plural to oblique indefinite plural. Is there any truth to the idea that this inflection means only a few and could be described as a paucal, or is this just completely mistaken?

Comment: I haven't an answer to the question; but from Wikipedia's end: that claim was added in 2013 by an editor who has not been active since 2022. 
I have tagged the claim there with {{citation needed}}. If somebody produces a reliable source here, I will add it to the Wikipedia article. If somebody convincingly argues that the claim is false, then I will remove it from Wikipedia.